# How to properly display swatches?

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches

Magento beginner here, using 1.9.2.4 and Ultimo theme

I have 2 attributes, color and size and would like to display them as swatches, not dropdowns on product pages.

I've configured attributes to appear as swatches on product category and product individual page, but they only appear on category and as dropdown on the product individual page, here is the configuration of the attributes and settings on the back-end:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd3yM.jpg

Contacted the theme dev and he said swatches are a core functionality of Magento.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Welcome to magento. plz share your category and product page's screen shots

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display size and color attributes as swatches insted of drop down, you can ebable it from admin

> Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Configurable Swatches >> General Settings >> enable

You can enable it from here.

Comment: Hi Patel,

I already did that and doesn't work

Comment: Check ultimo theme settings for it.